# Serenity: WebElementFacade doesn't detect the locator on mobile app

Tags: selenium, build.gradle, serenity-bdd, cucumber-junit, thucydides

I was defining the locators for both platforms using `WebElementFacade` and calling the defined WebElementFacade into the method.

when running the scripts, the locator defined using WebElementFacade doesn't detect on the mobile app for both platforms. Below is the code example used:

**Defining locators using WebElementFacade**

```
@AndroidBy(id = "buttonRed")
@iOSFindBy(id = "LogInButton")
private WebElementFacade signInBtn;
```

**Method using WebElementFacade**

```
Assert.assertEquals(signInBtn.getText(), "SIGN IN");
System.out.println(signInBtn.getText());
```

So at the moment to make the code work, I'm using locators directly in the method. Below is the code example:

**Method using without WebElementFacade**

```
if (isPlatformIos()) {
        Assert.assertEquals(find(By.id("LogInButton")).getText(), "SIGN IN");
        System.out.println(find(By.id("LogInButton")).getText());
    } else {
        Assert.assertEquals(find(By.id("buttonRed")).getText(), "SIGN IN");
        System.out.println(find(By.id("buttonRed")).getText());
    }
```

**build.gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.9.26'
    }

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'

dependencies {
    testCompile(
            'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:1.9.27',
            'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:1.9.12',
            'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.10.0'
}
```

On running the scripts, I don't see any specific error message but only `TimeoutException` from the logs.

**Error logs:**

```
TEST FAILED WITH ERROR: Verify user is taken to Home screen
---------------------------------------------------------------------
11:08:05.393 [Test worker] DEBUG net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - RELATED ISSUES: 
11:08:05.532 [Test worker] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - TEST FAILED AT STEP Verify first onboarding screen
11:08:05.533 [Test worker] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - Expected condition failed: waiting for LoginScreen.welcomeScreenTitle to be displayed (tried for 5 second(s) with 100 milliseconds interval)Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'System info: host: 'Lappy78', ip: '102.18.120.471', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_144'Driver info: driver.version: unknownBuild info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'System info: host: 'Lappy78', ip: '102.18.120.471', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_144'Driver info: driver.version: unknown
com.company.qa.RunTests > Login.Verify user is taken to Home screen FAILED
    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
        Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException

Expected condition failed: waiting for LoginScreen.welcomeScreenTitle to be displayed (tried for 5 second(s) with 100 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'Lappy78', ip: '102.18.120.471', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Expected condition failed: waiting for LoginScreen.welcomeScreenTitle to be displayed (tried for 5 second(s) with 100 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'Lappy78', ip: '102.18.120.471', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.throwNoSuchElementExceptionWithCauseIfPresent(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:888)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.checkPresenceOfWebElement(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:861)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.getText(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:952)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.thucydides.core.annotations.locators.AbstractSingleItemHandler.invoke(AbstractSingleItemHandler.java:45)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getText(Unknown Source)
    at com.company.qa.screens.LoginScreen.welcomeScreenTitle(LoginScreen.java:27)
    at com.company.qa.steplib.LoginUser.verify_first_onboarding_screen(LoginUser.java:17)
    at com.company.qa.steplib.LoginUser$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$722358e7.CGLIB$verify_first_onboarding_screen$0(<generated>)
    at com.company.qa.steplib.LoginUser$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$722358e7$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8b3b74e.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.invokeMethod(StepInterceptor.java:449)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.executeTestStepMethod(StepInterceptor.java:434)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runTestStep(StepInterceptor.java:409)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runOrSkipMethod(StepInterceptor.java:150)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(StepInterceptor.java:137)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(StepInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.company.qa.steplib.LoginUser$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$722358e7.verify_first_onboarding_screen(<generated>)
    at com.company.qa.steps.LoginSteps.verify_onboarding_screen(LoginSteps.java:23)
    at ✽.I am on first onboarding screen(src/test/resources/features/login.feature:7)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for LoginScreen.welcomeScreenTitle to be displayed (tried for 5 second(s) with 100 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'Lappy78', ip: '102.18.120.471', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:303)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:271)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.checkPresenceOfWebElement(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:855)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.getText(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:952)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.thucydides.core.annotations.locators.AbstractSingleItemHandler.invoke(AbstractSingleItemHandler.java:45)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getText(Unknown Source)
    at com.company.qa.screens.LoginScreen.welcomeScreenTitle(LoginScreen.java:27)
    at com.company.qa.steplib.LoginUser.verify_first_onboarding_screen(LoginUser.java:17)
    at com.company.qa.steplib.LoginUser$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$722358e7.CGLIB$verify_first_onboarding_screen$0(<generated>)
    at com.company.qa.steplib.LoginUser$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$722358e7$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8b3b74e.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.invokeMethod(StepInterceptor.java:449)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.executeTestStepMethod(StepInterceptor.java:434)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runTestStep(StepInterceptor.java:409)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runOrSkipMethod(StepInterceptor.java:150)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(StepInterceptor.java:137)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(StepInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.company.qa.steplib.LoginUser$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$722358e7.verify_first_onboarding_screen(<generated>)
    at com.company.qa.steps.LoginSteps.verify_onboarding_screen(LoginSteps.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:31)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:25)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:40)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:102)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:83)
    at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:58)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:118)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:56)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

As using the locators directly in the method, the lines of code is been increased as I feel and to reduce the line of coding for both platforms using WebElementFacade is the best practice.

Could someone help me to find out what's causing the issue for not detecting the locator using WebElementFacade, please?

Thanks in advance

Vamc

Answer (score 1):

It is working now like the below code is the example used.

```
@FindAll({
         @FindBy(id = "buttonRed")      //Android Identifier
         @FindBy(id = "LogInButton")   //IOS Identifier
)}
private WebElementFacade signInBtn;
```

As `@AndroidFindBy` or `@iOSFindBy` doesn't work with `WebElementFacade` so we need to use `@FindBy` for both platforms with different id's as above example.
Regards

vamc